# Is it possible to dual boot any flavor of linux on a intel compute stick (BOXSTK1AW32SC)

Tags: intel

The instructions I have found here seem limited to wiping the drive, creating FAT32, etc. I haven't seen a dual boot option outlined.

Also, I have been trying to chase down an Ubuntu 15.04 install ISO for the intel BOXSTK1AW32SC. There are references to it out there but the d/l links are broken.

TIA!

Comment: Ubuntu 15.04 reached EOL on Feb 4, 2016 (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2016/01/14/ubuntu-15-04-vivid-vervet-reaches-end-of-life-on-february-4-2016/)

Comment: Yes, EOL. Having said that, it apparently has been specifically tweaked for the BOXSTK1AW32SC to overcome 32bit bootloader limitation and problems with HDMI audio.

Comment: 15.04 can be found at http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/ but there will be no support for it.